# Hibernate could not extract ResultSet. Invalid column name

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have an issue with configure hibernate so it will store the data properly. In general I have a three objects, two primary tables and a foreign key table.

I am using Jackson to map the DTO to an entity and then I want to save the data.

**Table1:**

```
 @Data
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "Account")
 public class Account {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "AccountNumber")
  private String accountNumber;
  .....
  @Column(name = "LastModifiedDate")
  private LocalDate lastModifiedDate;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
  private List<AccountDevice> accountDeviceList;
}
```

**Table2:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Device")
public class Device {
 @Id
 @JsonAlias("mac")
 @Column(name = "MacAddress")
 private String macAddress;
 .....
 @JsonIgnore
 @Column(name = "LastModifiedDate")
 private LocalDate lastModifiedDate;
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "device")
 private List<AccountDevice> accountDeviceList;
 .....
 public String getMacAddress() {
    return macAddress;
 }
  public void setMacAddress(String macAddress) {
    this.macAddress = macAddress;
  }
 public List<AccountDevice> getAccountDeviceList() {
    return accountDeviceList;
}
public void setAccountDeviceList(List<AccountDevice> accountDeviceList) {
    this.accountDeviceList = accountDeviceList;
}
```

**foreign table:**

```
 @Data
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "AccountDevice")
 public class AccountDevice {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "Id")
  private Integer id;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "AccountDevice2Account", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_AccountDevice_Account"))
  private Account account;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "AccountDevice2Device", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_AccountDevice_Device"))
  private Device device;
  @Column(name = "LastModifiedDate")
  private LocalDate lastModifiedDate;
 }
```

This is how I am using repository in order to save the data:

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Flux<Timed<AccountDeviceDto>> mergedMonos = Flux.fromIterable(jsonList).flatMapSequential(Function.identity());
    mergedMonos.map(timed -> mapper.valueToTree(timed.get())).collectList().subscribe(list -> {saveAccountDeviceData(list);});

@Transactional
private void saveAccountDeviceData(List<Object> list) {
    
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        List<AccountDevice> accountDeviceList = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(list.toString(), AccountDevice[].class));
        if (!accountDeviceList.isEmpty()) {
            repository.saveAll(accountDeviceList);
```

I am not sure why but The problem is that MacAddress is not recognized

```
   reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: 
   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
   Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    .....
 
   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'MacAddress'.
```

Any advice what I am missing here ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have getter and setter methods for macAddress? I am not sure but it would be the problem.

Comment: Yes, I have update the main post. Thanks

Comment: @angus Did you try to enable sql logs and see generated sql?

Comment: it would be great if you could share a generated sql

Comment: Hi All, Thank you for your help. I found the problem. There was extra attr in Account object -> MacAddress. Rookie mistake.